# executing updates from local repository on ldap client from ldap server

Tags: ldap, openldap, ubuntu-16.04

i apologise in advance for being naive. i am super new to system administration.I have set up a local repository(in ubuntu 16.04 server) for my network(ubuntu 16.04 desktops).i have set up a ldap server in the ubutu server(open ldap and i am using phpldapadmin).my question is-
Is there any way to push updates to the ldap clients from the ldap server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**, not in the way you seem to be thinking.

While there are ways to have the client machines update, slapd (openldap-server) wouldn't not be used directly in those processes. Think ssh and a package manager (e.g. apt-get).

You ought to look into some sort of configuration management (e.g. ansible, puppet, chef, or salt).